# How to write integration tests for the views?

Tags: java, oracle, testing, integration-testing

For each database table being used by my system I created a view (for BI tools).

Views have no representation in the data model of the system (Java).

How can I best to write for the Views of integration tests?

Please help,
T.

Comment: Using JDBC?  Hibernate?  TopLink?  How does your Java access the database?

Comment: can you rephrase your question?